# Haskell String v. [Char]

Tags: string, haskell

I implemented the `isAlphaNum` (is letter or number) Haskell function. Note that it's already available in the `Data.Char` module.

```
import Data.Char (isAlphaNum)

isAlphaNum' :: String -> Bool
isAlphaNum' = all isAlphaNum

isAlphaNumChar' :: [Char] -> Bool
isAlphaNumChar' = all isAlphaNum
```

Based on these tests alone, I do not see a difference between either the `String` or `[Char]` types.

```
*ghci> isAlphaNumChar' "HEY" 
 True
*ghci> isAlphaNum' "Howdy" 
 True
*ghci> isAlphaNumChar' "Howdy" 
 True
*ghci> isAlphaNum' ['f', 'o', 'o'] 
 True
*ghci> isAlphaNumChar' ['f', 'o', 'o'] 
 True
```

What's the difference?

Comment: GHCi is sometimes helpful: `> :i String` .

Comment: For more fun, try typing `['f','o','o']` at the prompt and see what it spits out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String` is just an alias for `[Char]`:

```
type String = [Char]
```